# Providing iOS access to online files

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, networking, plist

Can I upload say a plist to a website online and have users access this data remotely?

In this way, I would be able to regularly update this data without updating the app constantly.

I suppose my real question is do you know a website that supports public file access?

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you cant just use a database? The infrastructure for something like that is really well built out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). Probably quite a few of other file hosters, but Dropbox (and the public folder) works like a charm.

Comment: This is not a long-term solution. Unless you don't have many users, Dropbox will rate limit you eventually and block access to the file. Looks like the limit currently is 20 GB per day. Some details here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/45/en

Comment: True, but if you need enterprise level hosting, you would get enterprise level hosting. Dropbox and it's limits are perfectly fine for testing and small builds. The smarter way is to simply to get a smaller hosting, but from the question wording, Dropbox is a valid answer.